# SEOing several videos effectively

Tags: seo, youtube

I'm new at the field of search-engine optimizing - I'm making video content on Youtube for a very long time, but I'm just an amateur guy. I have a lot of videos, including several video series.

Are there any way to add common content (such as tags, regular titles, etc.) that makes the SEO effectiveness of those videos better?

Moreover, what's the result of using regular titles, description and tags (e.g. World of X - part 1, World of X - part 2, etc.) in a series of videos? Because I suggest it makes them less interesting for people, but it may not cover the SEO effectiveness.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not **[about a website you control](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I attended one of those talks at Google on Youtube wherein they call different channel owners (creators) and help them build their channels. Some of the questions you are asking were covered in those talks. In case if you have your own channel and have uploaded 100+ videos, someone from the Youtube team would have contacted you regarding the same. Having said that, here are my thoughts -

The tags in Youtube are used to relate videos and help your audience find related videos when viewing one of your videos. What is used by searching engines on Youtube videos is titles and descriptions.

Why you should use regular titles is to indicate the presence of a series. Say for example I am searching for a recipe on how to create orange squash, and I find this awesome video having a title Summer Coolers - Orange Squash (this is just an example), then I would realize that the entire series would be on different cooler recipes. I would be more inclined to follow the channel ... the idea is to get the user to follow the channel.

The analogy that most creators draw here is that of a TV channel. If you have to run a schedule of your TV channel then would'nt you want that the different series running on your channel have a brand recall of their own (sometimes so strong that)? Hence the series names. Would advise you to take a look at [Creators Academy](http://www.youtube.com/yt/creators/creatoracademy.html).

Comment: In fact, I used regular titles mostly because copying title, description and tags from the previous video was way more convenient than rewriting the same every day. =)

Answer (score 0):

Your prime importance should be effectiveness of the title and description / summary of the video while submitting video at youtube.

One thing you can do is to use keywords etc in the first half of the title and in the second half write title that you believe is best for audience. You cannot use keyword in the second half as Google only consider title of less than and equal to 60 characters.